# Help with program for solving Project Euler Problem #8

Tags: c++

The program I wrote below seems to be doing its job, but it produces the wrong answer. As described in the comments, I need to multiply 5 consecutive digits of the 1000-digit string and then find the largest product throughout the entire string.

```
/*
OBJECTIVE: Multiply five consecutive numbers and then compare products to find largest product
PROVE: 40824
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // string length is 1000 characters
    string str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int store = 0; // what I need to compare total to later
    int total = 1; // total must be '1' for multiplication or result is always '0'

    for(int i = 0;i<=999;) // i = 0 because that's the starting point for place of first number in string (str[0]); because the length is 1 short, 999 is the limit
    {
        total = 1; // what will be multiplied by inputs from str[]
        int incr = i + 4; // places for the next 5 now that 0-4 are out of the way would be 5,6,7,8,9

        // A general note: pattern this generates is that the end digit of an even break in groupings will always either be 4 or 9
        // e.g. breaking the loop at position 44, 199, 234 will multiply 5 places properly without error

        if(i == 0) // when starting out i = 0
        {
            for(;i<=4;i++) // i = str[0] which is then incrmemented to str[4] which is fifth number
            {
                cout << "i: " << i << '\t' << "str[" << i << "]: " << str[i] << '\t';
                total*=(str[i] - '0'); // takes str[1],str[2],...str[4] and multiplies them together using total as valueholder.
                // " - '0' " is because string numbers return ASCII codes
                cout << "Total Product: " << total << '\t';
                cout << "Store: " << store << '\t' << endl;
            };

            store = total > store ? total:store; // if total is greater than store, then store = total; simple enough
            cout << endl; // line-break after first set of five
        };

        if(i>=5) // i is no longer 0
        {
            for(;i<=incr;i++) // i must be added by 5 now because 0,1,2,3,4 are first five and 5,6,7,8,9 are next
            {
                cout << "i: " << i << '\t' << "str[" << i << "]: " << str[i] << '\t';
                total*=(str[i] - '0'); // takes str[1],str[2],...str[4] and multiplies them together using total as valueholder.
                // " - '0' " is because string numbers return ASCII codes
                cout << "Total Product: " << total << '\t';
                cout << "Store: " << store << '\t' << endl;
            };

            store = total > store ? total:store; // if total is greater than store, then store = total; simple enough
            cout << endl; // line-break after each set of five
        };
    };

    cout << endl << endl <<  store; // final output; what should be answer

    return 0;
}
```

The program shows that it is indeed multiplying five consecutive digits together and successfully bumping the store value when necessary, alas I still get a wrong answer of 31752 which should be 40824 (According to the Project Euler Solutions google-group: http://code.google.com/p/projecteuler-solutions/). What have I done wrong? What must I do to fix this program? Any tips for the future to avoid the probably-stupid mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: '`for(int i = 0;n<=999;n++)`' are you sure you mean to initialise `i` and post-increment `n`? Also do you *really* need two inner loops?

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory glance, I believe your problem lies in the fact that you modify `i` in multiple locations aside from the `for` loop declaration. This would cause your scan through the number to skip over sequences that could have potentially been correct.\

If you reason out your code, it starts at position 0 in the string. Then you have a conditional where you increment `i` 4 times, so then the next time through the loop, you start attempting to find a sequence starting at position 4 in the string, rather than starting at position 1.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I completely neglected what "consecutive" meant at its most basic application to the string. Your solution should fix it :D

Comment: I believe you mean `starting at position 1`, since 2 would be the third character of the string.

Comment: Brilliant. It works. Introduced a second variable to keep track of single increments along the string and kept the other to keep track of each product loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Code:

```
/*
OBJECTIVE: Multiply five consecutive numbers and then compare products to find largest product
PROVE: 40824
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // string length is 1000 characters
    string str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int store = 0; // what I need to compare total to later
    int total = 1; // what will be multiplied by inputs from str[]
    int n = 0; // keeps track of single iterations

    for(int i = 0;n<=999;n++) // i = 0 because that's the starting point for place of first number in string (str[0]); because the length is 1 shorter, 999 is the limit
    {
        total = 1; // must be set back to one each successful product loop
        int incr = n + 4; // places for the next 5 after 0

        // A general note: pattern this generates is that the end digit of an even break in groupings will always either be 4 or 9
        // e.g. breaking the loop at position 44, 199, 234 will multiply 5 places properly without error

        if(n == 0) // string starts at 0, must be accounted for especially
        {
            for(;i<=4;i++) // i = str[0] which is then incrmemented to str[4] which is fifth number
            {
                cout << "n: " << n << '\t' << "str[" << i << "]: " << str[i] << '\t';
                total*=(str[i] - '0'); // takes str[1],str[2],...str[4] and multiplies them together using total as valueholder.
                // " - '0' " is because string numbers return ASCII codes
                cout << "Total Product: " << total << '\t';
                cout << "Store: " << store << '\t' << endl;
            };

            store = total > store ? total:store; // if total is greater than store, then store = total; simple enough
        };

        for(;i<=incr;i++) // i must be added by 4 now because 0,1,2,3,4 are first five and 1,2,3,4,5 are next
        {
            cout << "n: " << n << '\t' << "str[" << i << "]: " << str[i] << '\t';
            total*=(str[i] - '0'); // takes str[1],str[2],...str[4] and multiplies them together using total as valueholder.
            // " - '0' " is because string numbers return ASCII codes
            cout << "Total Product: " << total << '\t';
            cout << "Store: " << store << '\t' << endl;
        };

        store = total > store ? total:store; // if total is greater than store, then store = total; simple enough
        i = (n + 1); // i needs to start at a consecutive n each successful loop
    };

    cout << endl << endl <<  store;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, this problem makes me think of the Pattern Match Algorithm "KMP".
probably you should check out [KMP](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html), may gain some hint.